# How to export instantiated generic function to C

Tags: generics, export, ada

I create a generic function with Export and Convention aspects. Then I instantiated this function, but it ends up in my library with the 'r' suffix. Why this happens and how can I fix this?

For example:

```
generic
   I : int;
function Test_Generic return int
   with Export => True, Convention => C;

function Test_Generic return int is
begin
   return I;
end;

function Test is new Test_Generic (I => 5);
-- In library this function has name testr
```

Comment: What is Int? This does not compile because Int is not defined. It is a good idea to provide code that compiles.

Comment: I assumed it was Interfaces.C.int, and tested my solution with that.

Comment: Int is Interfaces.C.Int type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simpler answer is to move all aspects to the generic instance, but also add an External_Name aspect:

```
function Test is new Test_Generic (I => 5)
with Export, Convention => C, External_Name => "test";
```

I don't understand why External_Name is required here, and Export is not enough.

Comment: It looks like this is the best option at the moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have not been able to solve the problem fully, but here is a work-around, by moving the External and Convention aspects to a wrapper around the generic instance:

```
generic
   I : int;
function Test_Generic return int;

function Test_Generic return int is
begin
   return I;
end;

function Test_G is new Test_Generic (I => 5);

function Test return int
with Export, Convention => C;

function Test return int
is begin return Test_G; end Test;
```

It is a bit cumbersome, but seems to work.

Comment: Indeed interesting. From [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/ada/sem_ch12.adb;h=7e6aa8f6180e7dde2f060b5b9282174c637015c1;hb=HEAD#l5324) (note `Anon_Id`) and some lines later, at line 5451, it seems that GNAT always appends 'R' to the names of instantiated subprograms (which are, in themselves, wrapped in hidden packages, as shown when using `-gnatG`). Couldn't find any comments on exactly why 'R' is appended (or what the letter 'R' stands for) though. The code has been there since the initial commit of the GNAT front-end to the GCC repository.